# In jcanvas how to manipulate drawImage layer to apply instagram like filters on the image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, jcanvas

I have drawn a image on canvas using jcanvas drawImage method and this image is a layer

//Js part

```
$('canvas').drawImage({
      source: 'js/BN44094.jpg',
      layer: true,
      x: 0, y: 0,
      width: 800,
      height: 400,
      name: 'backImage',
      fromCenter: false
    });
```

//Html Part

```
<canvas id="canvas" width=800 height=400></canvas>
```

I want to apply instagram like image filters on this image, can some one guide me with this??

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to [this pretty clear explanation](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/imagefilters/) and then, depending on your needs, you can do [simple stuff like a green filter](http://projects.calebevans.me/jcanvas/sandbox/?code=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) and [pixel manipulation for advanced convolutions](http://projects.calebevans.me/jcanvas/docs/pixelManipulation/)